# Blockcypher Webhooks

Tags: blockchain

I am working on building a page to check whether is there any confirmed transaction for all the address in my wallet that i created.

```
$webHook->setUrl("https://requestb.in/r0dspfr0"); 
$webHook->setEvent('confirmed-tx'); 
$webHook->setToken('my_token'); 
$webHook->setWalletName('andy');
```

The problem here is i only want it to callback to that url whenever a transction had six confirmations.

I had tried to set the event to tx-confirmation or others, it cant work as what i want, it will always callback when there is only one confirmation, after that it stop.

Answer (score 0):

Are u using the Java sdk?

You can try "tx-confirmation" and only process the transactions with 6 confirmations

> **confirmed-tx**  Triggered for every new transaction making it into a new block; in other words, for every first transaction confirmation. This is equivalent to listening to the new-block event and fetching each transaction in the new Block. The payload is a confirmed TX.
>
> **tx-confirmation**   Simplifies listening to confirmations on all transactions for a given address up to a provided threshold. Sends first the unconfirmed transaction and then the transaction for each confirmation. Use the confirmations property within the Event to manually specify the number of confirmations desired (maximum 10, defaults to 6). The payload is a TX.

Comment: i'm using the php client, i had tried tx-confirmation but it is not working as well. It will always return me only when it is unconfirmed and the first confirmation then it stop.

Comment: I'm using an the JAVA sdk, and am getting a hit on my callback but the data is empty. I tried to contact them via email "support@blockcypher.com" but no reply. You could try contacting them too. Also are u getting proper data on the unconfirmed callback?

Comment: I am using php-client. How do you think i would specify the confirmations property. I tried calling `$webHook->setConfirmations(3);` and its not working